# Neataptic always returning same value after training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, synaptic.js

**EDIT:** I managed to get together couple of simple examples https://github.com/developer239/neural-network-playground

I just started playing with neataptic. I wanted to make the neural network to learn how to count using number: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

I normalized my inputs to 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9.

Then I wrote really simple training program that would teach the net how to add 1 + 2 (0.1 + 0.3).

```
const architect = require('neataptic').architect


const myTrainingSet = [
  { input: [0.1, 0.2], output: [0.3] },
  { input: [0.2, 0.1], output: [0.3] }
];

myNetwork = architect.Perceptron(2, 3, 1);

myNetwork.train(myTrainingSet, {
  log: 1,
  error: 0.01,
  iterations: 1000,
  rate: 0.3
});

console.log(myNetwork.activate([0,0]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([1,1]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([0.1,0.2]));
```

The problem is that this logs:

```
[ 0.3717501873608793 ]
[ 0.3695919770977549 ]
[ 0.37142744367869446 ]
```

It basically logs 0.3 for every input. Can some please explain what have I done wrong? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataset is too small for the neural network to learn from patterns. You have only provided it with samples that have `0.3` as output. The neural network minimizes its error by always outputting `0.3`, as that is exactly how it was trained. I have created an example with 1000 (dynamically generated) samples, which seems to work:

```
const architect = neataptic.architect;

const trainingSet = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    let integer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  let integer2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - integer1));

  let output = (integer1 + integer2) / 10;

  trainingSet.push({ input: [integer1 / 10, integer2 / 10], output: [output] });
}

myNetwork = architect.Perceptron(2, 3, 1);

myNetwork.train(trainingSet, {
  log: 50,
  error: 0.0001,
  iterations: 1000,
  rate: 0.3,
  momentum: 0.9
});

console.log(myNetwork.activate([0,0]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([0.1,0.2]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([0.5, 0.5]));
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8qpab71/)